# Club set functions coincide

Tags: set-theory, infinitary-combinatorics

Show that if $f,g:\omega_1 \to \omega_1$ preserve order (monotone increasing) and  are continuous ($f(\beta)=\sup\{f(\alpha) : \alpha<\beta\}$ for all limit ordinals $\beta<\omega_1$), then they coincide on a club set S, that is $f\restriction S = g \restriction S $.

Also, for how many functions can we generalize this statement? (for any finite number of functions seems logical if the statement is true, what about more)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINTS: For the first question, let $\alpha_0<\omega_1$ be arbitrary. Given $\alpha_n$, let

$$\alpha_{n+1}=\begin{cases}
f(\alpha_n),&\text{if }n\text{ is even}\\
g(\alpha_n),&\text{if }n\text{ is odd}\;.
\end{cases}$$

Let $\alpha=\sup_n\alpha_n$. What can you say about $f(\alpha)$ and $g(\alpha)$?

For the second question, what do you know about the intersections of finitely many closed unbounded sets? What about countably many?

Comment: I'm not sure, how does $\alpha$ look like? I realize that the sequence is derived from alternating between applying f and g, but what do we know about the sup of the sequence? Can we know that f(α)=supn(f(αn))? Because the definition requires we take the sup of f applied to all ordinals less than $\alpha$, not just the sequence.

Comment: @ctlaltdefeat: But remember, $f$ and $g$ are order-preserving, so the supremum of a cofinal subset is the same as the supremum of the whole thing. Then use the fact that $f$ and $g$ are continuous.

Comment: 1. Why does f and g being order-preserving mean that the supremum of a cofinal subset is the same as the supremum of the whole thing. 2. How do we know it's cofinal? We know that the countable sequence $\alpha_n$ is there, but there could still be a countably infinite number of elements less than $\alpha$ that are not part of the sequence, couldn't there?                    3. We are trying to claim that $f(\alpha)=g(\alpha)$, right?         4. All this refers to unboundedness, right?

Comment: @ctlaltdefeat: (1) You really should be able to prove that on your own. (2) By definition: $\alpha$ is the supremum of the $\alpha_n$’s, so of course they’re cofinal in $\alpha$; ordinals less than $\alpha$ that aren’t in the sequence are irrelevant. (3) Yes. (4) Yes: closure is immediate from the fact that $f$ and $g$ are continuous.

Comment: I still don't see the cofinality. Isn't $\omega$ equal to the supremum of finite even ordinals? Yet they aren't cofinal in $\omega$?

Comment: @ctlaltdefeat: It is, and they are: given any $n\in\omega$, there is an even $2k\in\omega$ that is greater than $n$.

Comment: Ahhh, I was thinking by cofinal you meant the complement of the set is finite. I get it now.

Comment: @ctlaltdefeat: I was beginning to suspect that you had some such misconception. I’m glad that we got it straightened out!